# Convert materials from cycles to bge as visible in viewport material shading mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine, opengl

In 2.78 the material viewport shading mode of cycles is greatly improved. In fact it is even better than BI in some aspects - for example it now correctly displays cube projection textures, something not available in BI or BGE viewport.

Clearly there is some (quite clever) code that converts cycles materials to OpenGL materials.

Is there a way to tap into that code (via interface or python) and get a game engine scene with these materials applied?